# Infragistics grid ( Row select )

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

I am using Infragistics WebDataGrid to display data.
I want to select first row by default.
I tried following code for the same but not working

```
 SelectedRowCollection selectedRows = gvHospital.Behaviors.Selection.SelectedRows;
 selectedRows.Add(this.gvHospital.Rows[1]);
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first row would be index 0, wouldn't it?  :)
Also, make sure you have supplied a data source and bound the grid first.